# I want to install flutter plugin pod install

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using the Flutter platform. I want to install the iOS pod but I am facing an issue with `pod install`. I have installed ruby and cocoapods but the pod is not installed successfully.

I have attached a screenshot so please check.

*Screen Preview:*
[image: Preview]

Thank you

Comment: You haven't said what pod you are trying to install or how you configured it. Without that information it's likely going to be impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps with commands:

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. Delete Podfile.lock file from the ios folder
4. cd ios
5. Delete Podfile from the ios folder
6. pod init
7. pod install
8. pod update

Comment: Not working I am facing same issue.

Comment: i update, check and process this steps again